# How to: Perform Inner Joins C# Programming

Tags: c#

```
[DataContract]
public class Produit
{
    [DataMember]
    public int id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string libelle { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string reference { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string prix { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Client
{
    [DataMember]
    public int id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string nom { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string tel { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string email { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string adresse { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Commande
{
    [DataMember]
    public int id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string numero { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string date { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public virtual Client client { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public virtual Produit produit { get; set; }
}
```

The code:

```
public List<Commande> getAllCommande()
        {
            try
            {
                var allCommande =
                from c in Service.Db.Clients
                from co in Service.Db.Commandes
                from p in Service.Db.Produits
                where c.id == co.client.id
                where p.id == co.produit.id
                select co;

                List<Commande> com = allCommande.ToList();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

Here is Exception

Additional information : Was the socket connection dropped. This can be caused by a mistake during the treatment for your message, for exceeding the waiting time of receipt by the remote host by e non underlying network resource issue. the waiting period was taken to local '00 : 00: 59.7860000 ' .

Please Help me

Comment: If you have too many from clauses in your query it'll drag performance down.

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx

but this maybe the answer

```
var allCommande =
    from commande in Service.Db.Commandes
    join client in Service.Db.Clients
    on commande.client.id equals client.id
    join produit in Service.Db.Produits
    on commande.produit.id equals produit.id
    select commande;
var allCom = allCommande.ToList();
```